# Can a KeyBinding be a Resource?

Tags: wpf, resources

I would like to create a StaticResource KeyBinding, but I cannot figure out how I would de-reference it.  So, in my Window.Resources, I might put the following:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <KeyBinding
                x:Key="CtrlRightKeyBinding"
                Modifiers="Control"
                Key="Right"
                Command="{Binding MyCommand}"
                CommandParameter="{Binding DirectionInfoRight}" />

        </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

However, I do not know how to de-reference it when setting my InputBindings:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
???
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Any thoughts or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="CtrlRightKeyBinding" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

See [StaticResource Markup Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750950.aspx).

Comment: Very strange.  I am trying to use the KeyBinding with a Button in a UserControl.  If I put the <KeyBinding> definition in the Button.Resources, your suggestion works.  However, if I put the <KeyBinding> definition in the UserControl.Resources, it does not work.  In both cases, The <StaticResource ResourceKey="CtrlRightKeyBinding" /> is under Button.InputBindings.